# Include js after bootstrap 4 bundle file

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to include js files after the `bootstrap.bundle.js`. i have this in my view

```
 $this->registerJsFile('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js', ['depends' => [yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset::className()]]);
 $this->registerCssFile('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css', ['depends' => [yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset::className()]]);
```

but when i view source. it still shows above it. any idea how to fix this? thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="/yii2/frontend/web/assets/949bae38/yii.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.0.18/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mhayes-twentytwenty/2.0.0-beta.1/jquery.twentytwenty.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<script src="/yii2/frontend/web/assets/949bae38/yii.validation.js"></script>

<script src="/yii2/frontend/web/assets/949bae38/yii.activeForm.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<script src="/yii2/frontend/web/assets/536f059b/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset` only loads bootstrap.css file. The bootstrap.bundle.js is loaded by `yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapPluginAsset`.
You only need to change the Asset class in that call like this:

```php
$this->registerJsFile(
    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js',
    ['depends' => [yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapPluginAsset::className()]]
);
```